# How to get number of gpu cards I have from a command line?

Tags: command-line, cuda, gpu, gpu-driver

I am trying to make a CUDA tool and I have to make it scalable. I need to give number of GPU a system have as an argument to my tool. Please tell me if there is any command for getting number of GPUs directly??

Comment: `lshw` is good when it comes to determining hardware.  If I'm not forgetting the syntax, `lshw -c graphics` should give you the desired result

Answer (score 13):

This command gets the number of GPUs directly, assuming you have `nvidia-smi`.

`nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader | wc -l`

It prints the names of the GPUs, one per line, and then counts the number of lines.

Comment: Easier to type from memory: `nvidia-smi -L | wc -l`

Answer (score 9):

```
nvidia-smi --list-gpus | wc -l
```

This will first list the GPUS one per line and then counts the lines of output which is the number of GPUS

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sudo lshw -C display` to list your video card(s), then google each one to see how many cores it has.

Comment: Since I want to make a tool, I don't think using sudo command will be safe.  Is there is any other way which do not require any  permission since my tool will be using the common server here.

Comment: And I don't want to see cores. I only want to get number of GPU cards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in a script, I'd suggest to using it like this:

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader | head -1
```

And also validate the number:

```
GPU_num="$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader | head -1)"
! [[ "$GPU_num" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "Not a number)"
```

It's better to count the number of lines, because the line can also be an error.